# Separating a data frame in terms of categorical predictors in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame, call it d, containing one continuous variable, and two categorical (0/1) variables.

Here is an example

```
structure(list(s = c(35.33, 39.51, 42.35, 42.35, 43.62, 43.77, 44.28, 44.32,44.74, 44.81, 47.71, 48.05, 48.13, 48.75, 49.4,49.44, 49.98, 50.27, 50.33, 50.54, 50.97, 51.2, 51.67, 51.94, 52.05, 52.7, 52.74, 52.82, 52.92, 54.17, 54.38, 54.57, 54.71, 55.53, 55.71, 56.11, 56.24, 56.29, 56.53, 57.16, 57.53, 58.04, 58.6, 58.8, 59.01, 59.26, 59.48, 59.61, 59.98, 60.54, 60.85, 61.89,62.01, 62.8, 63.22, 63.38, 63.78, 63.95, 67.08, 67.24, 67.54, 68.69, 70.16, 70.59, 72.15, 72.87, 76.69), age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c(">=30", "<30"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Men", "Women"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("s", "age", "sex"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L,15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to create 4 data frames containing the same continuous variable, one for each possible combination of the categorical variables: 00, 01, 10, 11. How can I do that in R ?

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image.  No one wants to type it all in again.  Instead,  use `dput(d)` to create a text version of your data that we can cut and paste into R.

Comment: `split(df,df[-1])` does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `split()` function:

```r
# Create a list holding the four dataframes
list.of.dfs <- split(df, paste(df$age, df$sex, sep="_"))

# check the result
lapply(list.of.dfs, head)
#> $`<30_Men`
#>        s age sex
#> 10 44.74 <30 Men
#> 12 47.71 <30 Men
#> 16 49.40 <30 Men
#> 18 49.98 <30 Men
#> 19 50.27 <30 Men
#> 20 50.33 <30 Men
#> 
#> $`<30_Women`
#>        s age   sex
#> 4  42.35 <30 Women
#> 5  42.35 <30 Women
#> 6  43.62 <30 Women
#> 7  43.77 <30 Women
#> 8  44.28 <30 Women
#> 11 44.81 <30 Women
#> 
#> $`>=30_Men`
#>        s  age sex
#> 15 48.75 >=30 Men
#> 25 51.94 >=30 Men
#> 27 52.70 >=30 Men
#> 37 56.11 >=30 Men
#> 38 56.24 >=30 Men
#> 40 56.53 >=30 Men
#> 
#> $`>=30_Women`
#>        s  age   sex
#> 1  35.33 >=30 Women
#> 3  39.51 >=30 Women
#> 9  44.32 >=30 Women
#> 14 48.13 >=30 Women
#> 21 50.54 >=30 Women
#> 30 52.92 >=30 Women
```

Comment: what you actually need `split(df,df[-1])`.. the splitting factor can be a list

Comment: For some reason, I cannot access the elements of those data frames. So if I do d=list.of.dfs[1], then d$s, I'm supposed to get the vector of s values, but I get NULL. Any idea why ?

Comment: @Onyambu 'what you actually need' is a bit strong -- they produce identical output with the difference that as I wrote it you a.) control what the names of the data.frames will be in the list without needing to know how it is autoformatted, 2.) the code will still run if your data.frame is in a different order or contains other variables.

Comment: @W.Volante try double brackets `d <- list.of.dfs[[1]]; d$s`